# Keep getting System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException when http binding was removed

Tags: wcf, https

I have a WCF based web api running on windows server 2012 iis.
and I've recently trying to remove the http and suddenly I got System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException error. If I add http binding back, it works again.

How can I fix it so that I can run it on https only? Thanks for helping!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
  <add key="appveripad" value="xx"/>    
</appSettings>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="3600" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" />
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <standardEndpoints>
    <webHttpEndpoint>
      <standardEndpoint name=""
                      transferMode="Buffered"
                      maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                      defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"
                      helpEnabled="true"
                      automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="64"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
    </standardEndpoint>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Set security mode to "Transport"?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the structure of web.conf for WCF has changed and been simplified a great deal.

I've fixed it myself by examine the exact windows log error in Event Viewer/Windows logs/Application.

The error message wrote

cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: An endpoint reference cycle was detected in your configuration. The following reference cycle must be removed: webHttpEndpoint/, webHttpEndpoint/. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxx\web.config line 111). --->
...
 Process Name: w3wp
 Process ID: 10396

And then I realized that I must remove now redundant endpoints that I have in the web.config file.

Below is the corrected part of the web.config that enables the https binding in the IIS. With and/or without http binding, it works. The only thing I did is I removed the endpoints and I added bindings sections.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="SecureTransport" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```